# How to add EventHandle _NOT_ at Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I'm making dynamic table at Page_LoadComplete, I cant do in at Page_Load becouse data can be changed during events process, so at Page_LoadComplete i make some buttons and want add them EventHandler:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   btn.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
}
```

But it doesnt work, how to add events to button not at Page_Load?

---

simple, even not dynamic code:

```
void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Label1.Text = "!!!";
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
}
```

on Page_Load works fine.

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
}
```

on Page_LoadComplete do nothing.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?  Or does the click event simply not fire?

Comment: event simply not fire, page just reload at it is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the example:
Given this html snippet:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="go_" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int ControlCount
    {
        get { return ViewState["Controls"] == null ? 0 : (int)ViewState["Controls"]; }
        set { ViewState.Add("Controls", value); }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ControlCount; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Click += btn_Click;
            b.Text = "Hi";
            form1.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Text = "bye";
    }

    protected void go_(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Hi";
        form1.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        ControlCount++;
    }
}
```

Every time you click the first button a new button will be added to the page with the text "Hi", and every time you click a "Hi" button the text for THAT button only will change to "Bye"

This works because I add the controls twice.  Once in the event handler of the main button, where I determine that I need a new control, and then AGAIN in OnLoad where I have a new, empty page again, but now I know (via ControlCount) how many controls I added.

Comment: intresting.. it starts to be clearer for me.
question about example: why clicked buttons dont become "Hi" again, it is clear said in Page_load `b.Text = "Hi";` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the control doesn't exist on postback (since you created it at run time).  Creating the control in Init should solve this, and will allow the event to fire.  You can change all of the properties in LoadComplete if you like, but the button needs to exist at that point.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying will never work because controls that are added dynamically must be REadded every time the page reloads.

Since your control population is based on the data being used in the form, you should put all your control creation logic in a single function, and in your event handlers, maniuplate the data then call your control creation logic function, while in Page Load you would JUST call the control creation function (presuming that you've already persisted the data between calls) so that all the controls that were created the first go around get recreated.  Then, once they have been recreated, they can respond to the events that they fired.

Comment: sorry, i spend about an hour to understand your answer, becouse my eanglish is bad and I'm new in asp.net, I have to ask you to repeat an answer simplier/clearer. thanks for understanding.

Comment: If you add a control using code, you must RE-add that control in PageInit or PageLoad before it can respond to events.  You cannot add a control in LoadComplete because event handling is over by then.

Comment: but on PageLoad I don't know the count of controls to add, it can changed on event handling term.

Comment: So in the event handling term, you need to capture information about how many controls to add, and persist that information so that in PageLoad you can recreate it.

Comment: stop, but event handling goes _after_ PageLoad.

Comment: But the controls must EXIST to handle the event, and they have to exist BEFORE page load completes.  I'll see if I can't draft up a simple example for you.